# Module method showing strange behavior

Tags: python

Guys I'm facing a problem on using this [module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/drawtree) which i install from `pip` currently my `OS` is Windows python36 64bit version is install. When i'm using and try to import this module

```
from drawtree import draw_level_order

draw_level_order('{3,9,20,#,#,15,7}')
```

Why python giving strange errors like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Root/PycharmProjects/untitled/src/Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from drawtree import draw_level_order
  File "C:\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\drawtree\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from drawtree import draw_bst, draw_random_bst, draw_level_order
ImportError: cannot import name 'draw_bst'
```

Comment: Update your `drawtree`. You're on an old version.

Comment: Actually, wait, the fixed version isn't on PyPI yet. It's only on the Github repo.

Comment: @user2357112 which python version is required to use this module

Comment: Which *Python* version? Python 2. There's a Python 3-compatible version of the module on [Github](https://github.com/msbanik/drawtree), but not on PyPI.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks my problem is solved github version is working fine convert comments into answer i will accept your answer

Comment: @user2357112 convert comments into answer i will accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `drawtree` on PyPI is not currently compatible with Python 3. There's a Python 3-compatible version on [Github](https://github.com/msbanik/drawtree), if you really want to use `drawtree` on Python 3.